# How to specify a Tensor on GraviPy instead of letting them be arbitrary functions

Tags: python, math

I would like to define a tensor on  GraviPy package, without letting its components being arbitary functions.

here is the [tutorial in docs](https://pypi.org/project/GraviPy/0.2.0/#files), but they only way I found a definition of tensor other than the generic form is this, which I really dont get.

```
def S_new_method(idxs): # definition
    component = (V.covariantD(idxs[0], idxs[1], idxs[2])
                 - V.covariantD(idxs[0], idxs[2], idxs[1])).simplify()
    S.components.update({idxs: component}) # memoization
    return component
S._compute_covariant_component = S_new_method
# _compute_covariant_component method was overriden
```

For example: I wanna set the tensor:

U_i = 2*x[i]

or something more complex